# How can I remove all special characters except brackets and hyphens(-)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to remove all special characters from string except braces `[]()` and hyphens `-`. I have this string `tr = "this (vehicle) has four [variants] : v1,v2,v3"` . I am trying to get `this (vehicle) has four [variants]  v1 v2 v3`

Now when I am doing `re.sub('[^[)A-Za-z0-9-]+', ' ', tr)`, I get `'this vehicle) has four [variants v1 v2 v3'`, so I did `re.sub('[^[)(]A-Za-z0-9-]+', ' ', tr)` but I got `'this (vehicle) has four [variants] : v1,v2,v3'`.

Also `re.sub('[^[)A-Za-z0-9-(]+', ' ', tr)` is returning `'this (vehicle) has four [variants v1 v2 v3'` but as soon as i put a closing `]`, it is not replacing anything. Is there a way to achieve this substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that produces the desired output!
i

```
mport re
mystring = "this (vehicle) has four [variants] : v1, v2, v3"
print(re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ()\[\]]+', ' ', mystring))
```

Comment: This seems to remove the space between v1, v2 and v3 (The output was `this (vehicle) has four [variants]  v1v2v3` ). Instead, change this to `re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ()\[\]]+', ' ', mystring)` which will give an output `this (vehicle) has four [variants]   v1 v2 v3`